# How to get ConfigurationProperty instance inside EnvironmentChangeEvent in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm experimenting with Spring Boot's reload actuator with the idea of being able to react to changes of the `application.yaml` file and adapt.

In my code, I am using `AppConfigurationProperties` class which is bound to the prefix `app` and holds the configuration properties. Changes to some of these properties require some action in the code.

This is why I thought I could tap into the a `ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent>` event which is fired after the reload event. Unfortunately this event is pretty useless to me, because I can't seem to figure out how to map the newly coming `PropertySources` to my `AppConfigurationProperty` class.

Trying to get the bean from the `event context` also fails because it gives the same instance:

```
ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) event.getSource();
MyConfigurationProperties newProps = context.getBean(MyConfigurationProperties.class);
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong here or I'm missing something.

Here's my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@EnableWebFlux
@EnableConfigurationProperties({AppConfigurationProperties.class})
@Slf4j
public class MyApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}


@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ToString
public class AppConfigurationProperties
{
    @Getter
    private final List<String> users;
}

@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserService
{

    private final AppConfigurationProperties properties;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    public SymbolPairRecorderService(AppConfigurationProperties properties)
    {
        // The purpose of this service is to subscribe/unsubscribe form some
        // websockets based on the `app.users` list. Changes to the list
        // should result in a `new websocket subscription` (for added users) 
        // or `disposal of existing subscription` (for removed users) 
        this.properties = properties;
    }

    public SymbolPairRecorderService()
    {
        this(new AppConfigurationProperties());
    }


    @Bean
    protected ApplicationListener<EnvironmentChangeEvent> onEnvironmentChange()
    {
        return event -> {
            ApplicationContext context = (ApplicationContext) event.getSource();
            // Okay, now what? How to get the new `AppConfigurationProperties` instance
            // so I could then make my own `diff` and proceed?
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this configuration  for signal a change in the environment:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @EventListener({EnvironmentChangeEvent.class, ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
    public void onRefresh() {
        // add your implementation
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the `ContextRefreshedEvent` is fired in this case? I am running this inside kubernetes and the only event I get so far is the `EnvironmentChangeEvent`. Maybe I'm missing something?